# Where to drive an old car in Havana

Tags: driving, car-rentals, havana

Cuba is famous for its 1950's and older American cars in daily use. And it's easy to catch a ride in a 1950's Chevrolet taxi.  But is there anywhere I can *drive* one of these old cars for a fee?

Comment: My guess is that it'd probably be easier to drive one for free (perhaps just befriend someone who owns a car) rather than for a fee. Businesses are few and heavily regulated in Cuba and it's doubtful that such a business idea ever managed to take off.

Comment: Just came [across this a couple of days ago](http://www.npr.org/blogs/thetwo-way/2015/03/27/395817280/nostalgic-cars-sour-automotive-fruit-of-cuban-embargo-gets-new-life). It's not clear whether you can drive the car yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a company that specializes in tours and/or rentals of nostalgic cars. They can be found at [NostalgiCar](http://www.nostalgicarcuba.com/en). They provide various tours, as well as airport transfers, but also provide the ability to rent the cars full time.